# Socket with Sails JS and React JS

Tags: reactjs, sockets, sails.js

I have an live Bid system. In Bid page we show Base and Bid Price of item. When any user update price of item then i want to reflect that price to all the customer who has Bid page open(without load).

**I want** to send message to client side from server when user update price of item. At client side when i receive server message, that will update table data.

**config/socket**

```
transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
```

**Server Side - In BidUpdateController [http://localhost:7039]**

```
sails.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   console.log("SOCKET ID : "+socket.id);
   sails.sockets.broadcast('bidUpdate',{ greeting: 'UPDATED!' });
   socket.on('disconnect', () => { // Is this necessary..?
     console.log('User disconnected');
   });
})
```

above code print socket id in my console...
SOCKET ID : wjMGczPrXtx5UpOrBBN3

**Client Side - In React Bid List page [http://localhost:3637]**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
React.useEffect(() => {
    let connectionOptions =  {
      "force new connection" : true,
      "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
      "timeout" : 20000,
      "transports" : ['polling', 'websocket']
    };
    
    const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7039',connectionOptions);
    console.log("SOCKET CONNECTION : "+socket.connected); // This return False
    
    socket.on('bidUpdate', (data) => { //This do nothing
      console.log("Response"+ data.greeting);
      //if i receive data then i will call function that update table data..
    });
      return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      }
 },[])
```

Above code print bellow things..
[React Page Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJzfN.jpg)

I just follow tutorials... and don't no exact concept...
can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

For broadcast to work you need to join the room first using `sails.sockets.join()`.
To broadcast a message to all sockets without joining a room, you can simply use `sails.sockets.blast()`. [Link to docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/blast)

In **BidUpdateController** you can simply

```
sails.sockets.blast('bidUpdate',{ greeting: 'UPDATED!' });
```

In **React Bid List** page

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import sailsIOClient from "sails.io.js";

React.useEffect(() => {
  // Create an instance of the io socket
  let io;
  if (socketIOClient.sails) {
    io = socketIOClient;
  } else {
    io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
  }

  io.sails.url = "http://localhost:7039"; // Set the server URL

  io.socket.on("connect", function onConnect() {
    console.log("This socket is now connected to the Sails server!");
  });

  const bidUpdateHandler = (data) => {
    console.log("Received response: " + data.greeting);
  };

  // Attach the 'bidUpdate' event listener
  io.socket.on('bidUpdate', bidUpdateHandler);

  // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    io.socket.off('bidUpdate', bidUpdateHandler);
  };
}, []);
```

if socket gets connected to server you will get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUBe8.png) in console